# Error while transforming Could not resolve import "child_process". in typescript

Tags: typescript, child-process

I am having simple ts project try run application getting below error in import 'Error while transforming Could not resolve import "child_process". ,
[image]
where tsconfig.json,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "lib": ["esnext.array", "esnext", "es2017", "dom", "WebWorker"],
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    // Only necessary because @types/uglify-js can't find types for source-map
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

In test.ts,

```
import { visualDiff } from '@web/test-runner-visual-regression';
import { setViewport } from '@web/test-runner-commands';
import * as child1 from 'child_process';

// startup code, runs before the tests run per browser
before(async function () {

  var foo: child1.ChildProcess = child1.exec(stubService.executable);
  console.log(typeof foo.on);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a test for code intended to be run in a web browser. But `child_process` [is provided by node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

If your code in running in a browser environment, then node.js does not exist there. Which means you cannot use `child_process` in test code that runs in a browser environment.

Whatever you are trying to do, you're going to have to find a way to do that works in a browser environment.